# How to set NULL to reactive within other reactive?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to set NULL to `reactive` upon clicking in a button. I wonder if it's possible to set NULL to `reactive` which is in another `reactive` - and more precisely to make second `reactive` to return NULL.
In my example below `data` (as module parameter) is passed as reactive from other module.

```
module_server <- function(id, data){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- NS(id)

# 1st reactive
reactive1 <-reactive(data())

reactive1(NULL)

# more code...
```

As you see and I tried to set NULL to reactive1 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to give it a NULL value when a condition is met? e.g.

```
reactive1 <- reactive({
 if(condition is met){
  data()
 } else {
  return(NULL)
 }
```

Comment: no, for example set NULL to `reactive` when button is clicked

Comment: clicking a button will create a condition? So you could use `if(input$button > 0)` for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is something Winston Chang calls 'catching the NULL'. The code by James will work, however, if you catch the null at the start, then anything that takes dependency on a reactive will also be null if the initial condition is not met. For example, if `r0` in the example below is `null`, then `r1` will also be `null`. Note that you don't have to explicitly set `r1` (or `r0`) to be `null`. My personal method is doing this:

```
r0<- shiny::reactive({
  if(!is.null(input$blah)){

    #do something here

  }
})

r1<- shiny::reactive({
  if(!is.null(r0())){
    #do some other thing
  }
})
```

Comment: The option with return(NULL) seems ok but I was thinking more about setting NULL to reactive e.g. when I click a button. So in case of `reactiveValues` I would do sth like `reactiveFunction$foo <-NULL`, in case of simple `reactive` I can't do the same e.g. `reactiveFunction({return(NULL})` doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to make a reactiveValue NULL when you click a button, use `observeEvent` around a button and store your reactive data values in a `reactiveValues` list. ie. `rv<- reactiveValues()`, `rv$blah<- 1`, `observeEvent(input$btn, {rv$blah<- NULL})`